# JUnit and Mockito test for FileUtils.copyURLToFile

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

How can I write the unit test using JUnit and Mockito for a method as simple as the following

```
public class FileUtil {
    public void copyURLToFile(String url, String filepath) {
        try {
            File file = new File(filepath);
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(url), file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have written but I'm not sure if it's right or not.

```
    public class FileUtilTest {
    private static final String TEST_URL = "http://www.test_url.com";

    private static final String FILEPATH = "tst/test_files/test_file.txt";

    FileUtil fileUtil;
    @Test
    public void copyURLToFileTest() throws IOException {
        File file = new File(FILEPATH);
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(TEST_URL), file);
        fileUtil.copyURLToFile(TEST_URL,FILEPATH);
    }
}
```

Can someone please advice?

Comment: What is your assertion?

Comment: There is none at the moment but I think a good assertion would be to check if the file contents are equal or not.

Comment: Right now you overwrite the file immediately. For a unit test you also don't want to rely on any URL which might not be available when the test runs. You want to "host" the file yourself. Yet, this method would not require any test in my opinion, as you aren't really doing anything other than converting parameters - its not business logic